# How can find location of PHP session save path?

Tags: php, session

I want to know the function name that tells the location of where the session is stored.

Comment: [so] is **not** an alternative to Google. Please do your research before creating a post.

Comment: See [this link](http://bit.ly/19UAKRp)

Answer (score 1):

`session_save_path()` returns the path of the current directory used to save session data.